# Interests calculation

Tags: calculus, finance

I'm trying to figure out how banks calculate their loan interests.

Let's say i ask the bank for `125 329,00 $` at a fixed interest rate of `0.99%` over `240 months`. In my own calc, I estimated a total loan interest of `12 522.18 $`.

Something like `52.18 $` month, a monthly payment of 574.38 $ with the pay back.

But looking at the banks' offer I see `575,82 $`  (`+1.44 $` diff) and I cant see any possible explanation for this. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The equation to calculate the monthly payment is

$$125329\cdot \left(1+\frac{0.0099}{12}\right)^{240}=x\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{0.0099}{12}\right)^{240}-1}{\frac{0.0099}{12}},$$

where $x=575.82$ is the constant monthly payment and $\frac{i}{12}=\frac{0.0099}{12}$ is the monthly interest rate.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and for providing the equation. It really helped me understanding how interests can be represented and calculated.

Comment: @Lothre1 It pleases me, that the answer has helped. You're welcome.